# After having installed WAMP, php files download when accessed through the browser instead of being run

Tags: wampserver

After having installed WAMP, I successfully accessed http://localhost/index.php which is the WAMP index page. So Apache is working properly.

I then copied my code into C:/wamp/www/mycode/ and tried to access it through http://localhost/mycode/somepage.php. Instead of running the script it downloads it at this point.

Moving the files to C:/wamp/www/somepage.php works perfectly fine though, so for some reason it won't allow me to have files in a subdirectory of the root folder.

My httpd.conf file includes the following types and handlers:

```
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

I have browsed through a large number of related problems but none have been able to solve my problem. The problem must be that for some reason I cannot run my php files in a subdirectory of the root folder. Also, I have tried running html files in said subdirectory and they work fine.

Comment: Hi, do you have a .htaccess file in the www folder ? or May be you have an apache directive that overwrite those handlers. [May be this old post could help](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3418477.htm) - last thing ; if there is nothing else install in your wamp environment, uninstall it and drop all the file from wamp dir then restart then installation and take care to use the correct 32bits/64bits regarding your OS (XP/Seven). Regards

Comment: just in case , did the PHP module load ? (1year later ;)

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem and if you actually never played with your server configuration settings, then your problem is 90% in your .htaccess file

Check your http://localhost/mycode/.htaccess file or try running your site without it.