# wamp localhost downloading index.php instead of displaying

Tags: php, apache, magento, wamp, wampserver

I have my Magento site on a domain. I have cloned my Magento files to my desktop. I have also import my database file using phpMyAdmin.

I am using Windows 7 and have installed wamp, put the cloned files into a folder under the www folder.

Now when I load my localhost, the page doesn't appear but it downloaded the file instead. I tried making a new folder under www folder and created a index.php file with phpinfo command line inside and it worked fine.

[image]

I have searched for answer for 2 days and still can't find anything to solve my problem and most of them were 2 years or more outdated.

Comment: Do one thing .. just debug your index.php file by putting **exit()** line by line and check which file or piece of code does this .

Comment: Also can you let us know what is your content after it gets downloaded ?

Comment: Hi Mit.agile, thanks for the help! The file it download is the index.php file. Also I have tried putting the exit() on each line in the index.php. I am unable to see any difference. It still download the file.

Comment: Make sure you have all required extension s enabled and you have pasted all required files in this folder.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600194/after-having-installed-wamp-php-files-download-when-accessed-through-the-browse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975639/site-saves-index-php-file-rather-than-opening-it-into-localserver-wamp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838021/running-php-file-asks-for-download-instead-of-executing-in-apache-2-5

Comment: Make sure you have copy pasted properly which should contain the files like cache folders , htaccess and other files which must be required for magneto

Comment: Does the WAMPServer homepage load when you put `localhost` in the browser address bar?

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Host to run your Magento site in? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Hi Riggs, the WAMPServer homepage load when I put localhost:8080 but it doesn't load when I put only localhost. I have also tried the Virtual Host method but it's still the same.

Comment: Hi Mittul, I cloned the source files from bitbucket directly into my desktop using git bash so I guess I won't left out any files.

Comment: I have decided to uninstall the WAMP and install XAMPP instead. This is taking me too much energy and time, wasted 1 week just to try and solve this issue. Thanks guys anyway.